# How to store unlimited data in a TEXT column

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying store a large amount of data in a column with a datatype of TEXT but I am getting this error - `sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (pymysql.err.DataError) (1406, &quot;Data too long for column 'records' at row`

Is there another datatype I can use that can contain unlimited number of text. 
This is my code:

```
records = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True) //defining the column

//inserting records
new_trans = Transaction(account, customer_id, str(records), created_at)
db.session.add(new_trans)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Use LONGTEXT - it allows up to 4Gb text... but you'll oversize the packet.

Comment: You could always [serialize](https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/serialization/) the text first. There's no such thing as unlimited storage.